# The zeta function and classical mechanics

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4358), Guilherme França and André LeClair show that $$\gamma_{y}\sim 2 \pi  \left(y-11/8\right)/W\left((y-11/8)e^{-1}\right)$$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function, and $\gamma_{y}$ is the imaginary part of the the $y$th non-trivial zero along the critical line. This formula can then be used in a similar way to Gram points for finding zeta zeros.

When this function replaces $y$ in $\zeta(1/2+iy)$, and the real and imaginary parts are plotted parametrically, the result shares superficial similarities with a limaçon:

[image]
[image]

where one complete orbit is made approximately in every integer interval.

Firstly, analysing the limaçon in terms of its orbit seen as a particle travelling at constant velocity around the origin, comparing curvature, distance from origin, and non-directional "speed", where

\begin{align}
&x(t)\text{:=}\cos (t)+\cos (2 t)+1&\\
&y(t)\text{:=}\sin (t)+\sin (2 t)&\\
\end{align}

the solutions to

\begin{align}
t\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{2 \left(x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2\right)^{3/2}}{\left| x'(t) y''(t)-x''(t) y'(t)\right| }=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}
\end{align}

are clearly

\begin{align}
t=2\pi n-\cos^{-1}(-5/4),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=2\pi n+\cos^{-1}(-5/4),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=\dfrac{2}{3}(3\pi n-\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
t=\dfrac{2}{3}(3\pi n+\pi),n\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\end{align}

[image]

Interestingly, the zeta function has similar properties when analysed in this way. Since

\begin{align}
|Z(x)|=\sqrt{\Im\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i y\right)\right)^2+\Re\left(\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+i y\right)\right)^2}
\end{align}

where $Z$ is the Riemann-Siegel Z function, $\sqrt{\Im(f(y))^2+\Re(f(y))^2}$ is zero at $\gamma=2 \pi  \left(y-11/8\right)/W\left((y-11/8)e^{-1}\right),$ for

\begin{align}
&f(\text{y})\text{:=}\zeta \left(2 i \pi  \left(y-11/8\right)/W\left((y-11/8)e^{-1}\right)+1/2\right)&\\
&v(y)\text{:=}\sqrt{\Im\left(f'(y)\right)^2+\Re\left(f'(y)\right)^2}\\
&\kappa (y)\text{:=}\frac{\left| \Re\left(f'(y)\right) \Im\left(f''(y)\right)-\Im\left(f'(y)\right) \Re\left(f''(y)\right)\right| }{\left(\Im\left(f'(y)\right)^2+\Re\left(f'(y)\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}\\
&d(y)\text{:=}\sqrt{\Im(f(y))^2+\Re(f(y))^2}
\end{align}

a plot of $\{v(y),2 \pi /\kappa (y),\pi  d(y)\}$ with gridlines at $\gamma=2 \pi  \left(y-11/8\right)/W\left((y-11/8)e^{-1}\right)$ looks like this:

[image]

where it can be seen that $\{v(y),2 \pi /\kappa (y)\}$ intersect at the zeta zeros.

```
f[y_] := InputForm[Zeta[Rational[1, 2] + Complex[0, 2] Pi (Rational[-11, 8]
+ y)/ProductLog[E^(-1) (Rational[-11, 8] + y)]]]
v[y_] := InputForm[(Im[Derivative[1][f][y]]^2 + Re[Derivative[1][f][y]]^2)^
Rational[1, 2]]
\[Kappa][y_] := InputForm[Abs[Im[Derivative[2][f][y]] Re[Derivative[1][f][y]] - 
Im[Derivative[1][f][y]] Re[Derivative[2][f][y]]] (Im[Derivative[1][f][y]]^2 + Re[
Derivative[1][f][y]]^2)^Rational[-3, 2]]
d[y_] := InputForm[(Im[f[y]]^2 + Re[f[y]]^2)^Rational[1, 2]]
r = 2; rr = 15;
zeros = Rest@   Table[y /.      FindRoot[
  2 Pi (-11/8 + y)/LambertW[(-11/8 + y)/E] == Im[ZetaZero[n]], {y,n}], {n, r, rr}];
Plot[{v[y], 2 \[Pi]/\[Kappa][y], \[Pi] d[y]}, {y, r, rr}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Garnet", 
Filling -> {1 -> {2}, 2 -> {3}}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
ImageSize -> 400, GridLines -> {zeros, {}}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
Point[Transpose@{zeros, Table[v[y], {y, zeros}]}]
```

It can be seen then that there is clearly a close relationship between the curvature of $f(y)$ *(ie $\kappa(y)$)*, the speed of a particle moving along the path of $f(y)$ *(ie $v(y)$)*, and the distance from origin *(ie $d(y)$)*.

My question then is how would I go about finding the solutions to

\begin{align}
A=\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}:v(y)=\dfrac{2\pi}{\kappa(y)}\right\}
\end{align}

analytically? And for

\begin{align}
B=\left\{y\in\mathbb{R}:\gamma=2 \pi  \left(y-11/8\right)/W\left((y-11/8)e^{-1}\right)\right\}
\end{align}

is it true that $B\in A$ ?

## Update

In response to მამუკა ჯიბლაძე's comment, it certainly seems from a quick numerical check that $v(y),2\pi/\kappa(y)$ don't actually intersect at the zeta zeros, but are related to their approximations:

```
yy = y /. Table[FindRoot[v[y] == 2 Pi/\[Kappa][y], {y, n}], {n, 1, 20}];
y1 = Table[w[yy[[y]]], {y, 1, Length@yy}] // N;
y2 = Table[Im@ZetaZero[y], {y, 1, Length@yy}] // N;
y3 = Table[w[y], {y, 1, Length@yy}] // N;
ListLinePlot[{Table[(Log[y2[[y]]] - Log[y3[[y]]])/(2 Pi y^(3/2)), {y, 1, 
Length@yy}], y1 - y2}]
```

[image]

where for

\begin{align}
&w(y):=2 \pi  \left(y-11/8\right)/W\left((y-11/8)e^{-1}\right)\\
&r_{y}:=\text{solutions to }v(y)=2\pi/\kappa(y)
\end{align}

the above is a plot of $(\log(\gamma_{y})-\log(w(y))/(2\pi y^{3/2})$ against $w(r_{y})-\gamma_{y},$ so it would seem that $B\notin A.$

However, I am still unsure how to show this analytically, and since $(\log(\gamma_{y})-\log(w(y))/(2\pi y^{3/2})$ is just a rough guess, I would be interested to know whether there is a more accurate definition of the relationship between $r_{y}$ and $\gamma_{y}$.

Comment: What does the first equation mean? Specifically, what is y?

Comment: $y$ corresponds to the $y$th zeta zero.

Comment: eg $y=1$ gives *first equation*$=14.5213\dots\sim\Im\rho_1,$ etc.

Comment: Do the graphs of $v$ and $2\pi/\kappa$ intersect at the zeros or at their approximations? And do you know anything about accuracy of the approximation? From what I was able to understand the error term grows like logarithm of $y$, or is this wrong?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for your response. Please see update.

Comment: The first equation would imply that asymptotically 100% of the nontrivial Riemann zeros are on the critical line. This is a famous open problem, so I doubt the authors have a valid unconditional proof.

Comment: @GHfromMO sorry, yes - should have stated this only applies to zeros on the critical line - will update.

Comment: @martin: Yes, and that is how I understood it. The claimed equation for the zeros on the critical line would imply that only 0% of the nontrivial zeros are off the critical line. We certainly don't have a proof of that.

Comment: @GHfromMO Are you saying that if there are zeros off the critical line, the formula is not valid asymptotically for the ones that are on it?

Comment: Yes. If there are more than 0% nontrivial zeros off the critial line, then the equation fails for the zeros on the critical line. The reason is simple: the equation is true for all the zeros in the critical strip, because we know asymptotically the number of such zeros up to a given height.

Comment: @GHfromMO ah, ok, so it would be a weaker asymptotic

Comment: We have no asymptotic for the zeros on the critical line, because we have no idea how many zeros are on the critical line. We know more than 40%, but the ratio might fluctuate between say 67% and 93% as far as I know. Please delete the remark "as GH from MO pointed out below, this only applies to the zeros on the critical line", because I never said this.

Comment: @GHfromMO sorry, I misunderstood - now deleted. Your point is interesting - I didn't realise this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18162/discussion-between-martin-and-gh-from-mo).

Comment: In general I am skeptic about proofs by physicists. They have different rules, different motivations, different styles.

Comment: @GHfromMO yes! So would "assuming the RH" be more accurate?

Comment: I continued in chat.

Comment: @GHfromMO apologies for earlier - I was travelling at the time and went completely out of signal area. I see your point though that $W(x)$ is asymptotically $\log(x)$.

Comment: @GHfromMO does RH imply something about the validity of the alleged formula with Lambert W? If you have an oracle that computes the $n$-th zero (possibly on the critical line) and compare it with with the alleged formula, does this imply something about the validity of the formula or RH? (for some reason can't join the chat).

Comment: @joro: The alleged formula merely says, assuming standard notation, that the imaginary part of the $n$-th zero on the critical line is asymptotically $2\pi n/\log n$. This is true if and only if asymptotically 100% of all nontrivial zeros are on the critical line (when ordered by imaginary part). In particular, the alleged formula is true under RH. These are all simple facts.

Comment: We could not claim a proof of the RH,  but not for the reasons discussed here.    GH from MO,   I think is referring to the fact that N(T),  the number of zeros on the entire critical strip,  is known,  so if one assumes the RH,   one can obtain our formula.   But that is not how we obtained our formula.   We did not assume the RH nor N(T).     The Lambert expression is only an approximate solution to an exact equation for the n-th zero.   However we could not prove that there was a solution to this equation for every n.

Comment: @AndréLeClair thank you for responding and clarifying - I must admit, I was not absolutely clear on what was being implied in the comments, but without a full answer to the question, there is only so much that one can say. I really appreciate your clarification here.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at our most recent paper,  from a few weeks ago.  Still not complete,   but gaps are closing.   It helps to explain why there is a unique solution for the  equation for the n-th zero that we proposed.

Comment: @AndréLeClair Thanks, yes, I certainly will - hopefully it will clear up a few things for me.